# Error in create master key

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to do a master key, but the following error occurs

my error is

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'master'.
```

my code is

```
USE EncryptTest 
GO
create  master key encryption by password='al4jklklkl@kjkjkFdi';
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    USE AdventureWorks2012;
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe';
    GO
```